# What do you call graphs that allow edges to edges?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

For something I’m trying to model, it looks like the most natural mathematical structure is a [port graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2597225/34989) where an edge can connect a port to a port, a port to an edge, or an edge to an edge.

Is there a standard name for such a graph? Ignore the ports if that helps. The main point of divergence from ordinary graphs is that edges can serve as endpoints of edges. What should I google for to find existing literature about this kind of graph? I'm pretty sure it's not equivalent to a hypergraph; it's more restricted.

If this kind of structure is nonsensical or there’s a conceptual “neighbor” that makes more sense for most applications, please tell me about it. I’d love to be talked out of using this kind of graph. So far, I've barely started with it and it’s already caused me headaches.

Comment: Can an edge connecting an edge to an edge be connected via an edge to another edge connecting an edge to an edge (if you catch my drift)?

Comment: @CliveNewstead Yes. To paraphrase an old Wendy's commercial, edges is edges. And yes, though this idea is meant to simplify things, it also introduces new ways to get confused, hence my reluctance to use it. If there's some existing research literature about this sort of graph, that might reduce my uncertainty about whether it's worth it to spend more time going down this particular rabbit hole.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these, but in case it helps, here's a way of thinking about it. A graph, in the usual sense, consists of a set $V$ of vertices, a set $E$ of edges, and a function $\partial:E\to V^{(2)}$ assigning to each edge $e$ the set $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of its vertices. Usually we take $E\subseteq V^{(2)}$ and take $\partial$ to be the inclusion function. Your structure consists of a set $V$ of vertices, a set $E$ of edges (disjoint from $V$), and a function $\partial:E\to (V\cup E)^{(2)}$. I suspect that with some trickery you can encode such structures as usual graphs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Indeed these graphs map to ordinary graphs in a simple way: each node, port, and edge in the graph with no name $G'$ maps to a distinct node in the ordinary graph $G$. The ordinary graph $G$ has edges that link each node in $G'$ to all its ports, and edges that link each edge in $G'$ to whatever it's incident to.